# Bootstrap popover not working on joomla site

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, popover

Currently working on this page:
http://www.sagu.edu/tv/channels/seminars

I took the example from here:
http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-tutorial.php

I suspect that joomla might be including a resource that might be causing the conflict where the popover doesn't show.

The code that I have in the page is:

```
<div class="custom"  >
    <h2>Example of creating Modal with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover" href="#" id="example" rel="popover">hover for popover</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I then have the script's function on the bottom:

```
<script>
    $(function ()
    { 
        $("#example").popover();
    });
</script>
```

However if you look at the header for joomla, you'll find a bunch of resource files.  Not sure which one is causing the conflict or if I'm missing a resource.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem.  Is there a way to call the popover command with a generic ID?  For example if I have ten items, instead of creating a function for each one, is there a generic way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put jquery before all scripts, if you have bootstrap.js, you not need include bootstrap popover.js again, because are include in bootstrap.js, use bootstrap CDN, is better, try it.
you have 2 jquery loading at head

Comment: I tried copying and pasting the twitter bootstrap example into google chrome's "edit as html" option with the resources hardcoded and the popover still doesn't show.  Is there a way to determine the error?

Comment: Your answer helped me figure out something with the libraries.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In many jQuery Frameworks to prevent the conflicts, the Developers uses a variable instead of `$` symbols. Instead of using the jQuery before all scripts. Just find that variable which is replaced for `$` and use it in your code. Then only you can use the full functionality of the Framework.